# Ayuda con ClassCastException con reflexion en hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, reflexión, casting

Alguien puede apoyarme con esta excepción: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`
Ocurre cuando ejecuto el siguiente código en un DAO para usar hibernate. El problema esta en la función **getEntityClass()** y me extraña porque he utilizado este mismo código (clase GenericDAOImpl) en otros proyectos y funciona correctamente:

```
    public class GenericDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {
        public GenericDAOImpl() {...
        public T create() {...
        public void save(T entity){...
        public void update(T entity){...
        public void saveOrUpdate(T entity){...
        public void delete(ID id){...
        public List<T> findAll() {...
        public T get(ID id) throws Exception {
                Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();          
                T entity = (T) session.get(getEntityClass(), id);//Error aqui
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                return entity;
        }
        private Class<T> getEntityClass() {
//En esta linea es donde ocurre el error
                return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
    }
    public class Main {
        static GenericDAOImpl<SalesPerson, Long> salespersonDAO=new GenericDAOImpl<SalesPerson, Long>();
        static GenericDAOImpl<Sale, Long> salesDAO=new GenericDAOImpl<Sale, Long>();

        private static void loadSalespeople(){
            SalesPerson sp1=new SalesPerson("Eugenia Martinez",30000f,0.15f);
            SalesPerson sp2=new SalesPerson("Alfredo Perez",33000f,0.20f);
            try {
                salespersonDAO.save(sp1);
                salespersonDAO.save(sp2);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private static void saveSales(){
            Sale sale1=new Sale(1200.0,0.1f,new Date());
            Sale sale2=new Sale(650.0,0.25f,new Date());
            try {
               //Con esta linea continua el error
                SalesPerson sp1=(SalesPerson)salespersonDAO.get(1L);
                sp1.add(sale1);
                sp1.add(sale2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private static void deleteSales(){
            try {
                salesDAO.delete(11L);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main.loadSalespeople();
            Main.saveSales();//Aqui empieza el error
            Main.deleteSales();
        }
    }
```

**Actualizado:**

```
@Entity
public class Sale implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private double total;
    private float discount;
    private Date salesDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idsalesperson")
    private SalesPerson salesperson;
    //Constructor default
    //Constructor total,discount,discount
    //setters, getters y toString
}
```

y

```
@Entity
public class SalesPerson implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;
    private float commission;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="salesperson",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Sale> sales=new HashSet<Sale>();
    //Constructor default
    //Constructor name,salary,commission
    //Metodo add(Sale sale)
    //setters, getters y toString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como esta tu Entity Sales, SalesPerson y demas? Tienen el Extend del Entity Respository, Como esta el Entity Repository. Si podrias postear esas dos clases seria mas claro

Dos posibles Soluciones despues de hacer pruebas.

Una si estas usando Spring puede ser problemas de que existe problemas con las librerias por que en Spring Entity Repository no es de tipo ParameterizedType, solo esta con extends entonces hay que hacer algunos parseos.

```
     private Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        Type genericSuperClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); // OBTENEMOS NUESTROS CLASES
        ParameterizedType parametrizedType = null; // INICIAMOS EL TIPO DE PARSEO
        while (parametrizedType == null) { // MIENTRAS ES NULO
            if ((genericSuperClass instanceof ParameterizedType)) { // SI ES EXTENDS
                parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperClass; // CASTEAMOS RECIEN  A ESA CLASE 
            } else {
                genericSuperClass = ((Class<?>) genericSuperClass).getGenericSuperclass();
            }
        }

      entityClass = (Class<T>) parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; 

 return entityClass; // RETORNAMOS RECIEN 
    }
```

Otra posible solucion cambiar tu Entity Repository

Comment: ya puse las clases

Comment: Ya puse un tipo de solucion me avisas si es que da o no.

Comment: Type es de tipo java.lang.reflect.Type??? le puse ese tipo. `entityClass` tambien me marca error no se de que tipo es, pero le puse `return (Class<T>) parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];` pero aun así trono en `genericSuperClass = ((Class<?>) genericSuperClass).getGenericSuperclass();` marca java.lang.NullPointerException